# Pokemon Go crashes on startup?

Tags: technical-issues, pokemon-go

I can open Pokemon Go, but it only shows a blank white screen. Shortly after this, the app crashes. Could you assist me?

I have heard that the servers may have been hacked, however I can not verify this. My device can open it, however I can not access any functions. I have a device with the following:

Manufacturer: Acer
Model ID: B1-730HD
CPU Vendor: Intel
CPU Speed: 1.60 GHz
CPU Version: Clover Trail + Z2560
CPU core: 2 cores
ROM size: 8GB
RAM size: 1GB

I downloaded the app with the Play Store, this is also the first time I'm running it.

Comment: Is there a problem with the question?

Comment: Some people vote without helping to get things clear. You get used to this... Anyway, is your device capable of running the game?/what device do you have? Did you download the game via app/play store? Did it run earlier or is it your first time running it?

Comment: Very few of our users possess a crystal ball. As such, we cannot answer questions that contain too little information to accurately answer them.

Comment: To dly, my device can open it, however I can not access any functions. I have a device with the following:
Manufacturer:Acer
Model ID:B1-730HD
CPU Vendor:Intel
CPU Speed:1.60GHz
CPU Version:Clover Trail + Z2560
CPU core: 2 cores
ROM size: 8GB
RAM size: 1GB

I downloaded the app with the playstore.
Also, this is my first time running it.

@dly

Comment: Looks like it is barely capable of running it. Please append the device information to your question and when exactly it crashes. The you can vote to reopen the question to get some answers.

Answer (score 2):

Pokémon Go does not support Intel processors. You can see this on their [Support Page](https://support.pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/hc/en-us/articles/221958248-Supported-devices).

For Android phones, these are the specifications you need:

> - Android 4.4 to Android 6.0.1
>
>   - (Android N will not supported until the official Android release)
> - Preferred resolution of 720x1280 pixels (Not optimized for tablet)
> - Strong internet connection (Wi-Fi, 3G, or 4G)
> - GPS and Location Services
> - *Intel CPUs are not supported*